# GAE : What is the preferred way of ensuring an outside task really finishes?

Tags: google-app-engine, task

I have a workflow that consist of doing some heavy work outside of Google AppEngine by adding tasks to a Redis queue. The outside servers that treats the Redis queue send a POST request back to GAE once the work is done.

The issue is that sometime, the Redis queue fails, or at last the POST request isn't made. This results in a "waiting" state on GAE that never changes.

In order to fix that issue, I plan to implement a "healthcheck" system that will automatically close the state to "invalid" after some time that have elapsed, but I was wondering which one was the best way to do it, in term of resources & pricing.

**Option 1** : When I submit a task to the Redis queue, I would also create a new GAE task, called "Healthcheck", that would be run in 5 minutes, and if the current task is not done, switch it to "invalid" and close it.

**Option 2** : When submitting the task to the Redis queue, I hang th process using a `while True` loop and refresh the current state up until it switched to done. I would also set up a `Deadline exception` watcher that would update the status to "invalid" when the Deadline is called by GAE (in general, 10 minutes).

PROs/CONs :

- The option 1 has the advantage of not having a hang process, thus using less resource in my opinion. The Cons here is that I will have as many "healthcheck" tasks as tasks added to the Redis queue (around 30k/day)
- The option 2 has the advantage of not creating a new GAE task, but will consume more resource (useless in my opinion).

Is there a third way to do it I didn't think about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tasks are free to use (*except storage space that is very cheap*). I don't see why number of tasks is a con.

The 2nd option is not an option in my opinion as is expensive and process can die at any time.

The 3d option would be to have a cron job to query records that are in "running" state for more then defined deadline. That would require composite index on 2 fields (status, dt_created) - will be more expensive comparing to option #1.

Go with tasks.